# How do i hide API key when it must be wrapped in apostrophe?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers

I'm struggling a bit on how to hide the API key that is located in my header.

JavaScript:

```
headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Token token="API TOKEN HERE"'}
        }
```

Because the 'Authorization' and 'Token token=' are wrapped in apostrophe i can't put in a variable because it would then be seen as a string and the API will deny my request.
I tried using string interpolation but didn't work.
The documentation for the API said that the API token needs to be in the header.

The API i use [FavQs](https://favqs.com/api)

Comment: Check out ES6 template syntax with backticks.

Comment: @DominikMatis I did try string interpolation(backticks), didn't work either

Comment: 'Authorization': ``Bearer ${token}``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem is,
was reading the [MDN Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and found this:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
```

Was so hung up on the apostrophe and put it in my code as well, but the API part didn't need it.

My code works now:

```
headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Token token=${apiKEY}`}
```